# Facebook integration iOS 7 issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Just switched to XCode 5 and iOS 7 on my macbook , thoughts everything will work correctly since I wasn't doing anything special but it doesn't work.

I had facebook integration on my 6.1 app ,this is what I was doing:

```
- (IBAction)facebookTapped:(UIButton *)sender {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //Check if the net is reachable
        SLComposeViewController * faceSheet=[self.socialIntegration showFacebook:@"text" andImage:nil andLink:@"link" andView:self];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //[self netConnectionTrue:cell Connected:answer];
            //[tempAlertView show];
            [self presentViewController:faceSheet animated:YES completion:NO];

        });
    });


}
```

now when I press the button this is what I get:

> +[SocailIntegration modalTransitionStyle]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x49b30

and the app breaks on this line:             `[self presentViewController:faceSheet animated:YES completion:NO];`

anyone knows why this might happen?

**EDIT:This is my code in socialIntegration class:**

```
-(SLComposeViewController *) showFacebook:(NSString *) initialText andImage:(NSString *) imageName andLink:(NSString *) link andView:(UIViewController *) controller {

    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *faceSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [faceSheet setInitialText:initialText];
        if (imageName.length!=0)
        {
            [faceSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
        }
        if (link.length!=0)
        {
            [faceSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
        }
        return faceSheet;
        //[controller presentViewController:faceSheet animated:YES completion:nil];


    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                  message:@"You can't send a status right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Facebook account setup"
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `self.socialIntegration` - it doesn't like you're calling an iOS API, so I assume it's something you've either put together yourself or a third party piece of code?

Comment: @lxt its a class I use to gather twitter and facebook together, I added the code that is used in socialIntegration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom `socialIntegration` class has a bug in it. It only returns a `SLComposeViewController` if Facebook is available on the device. If it isn't, it returns nothing.

However, you don't test for this when you actually call it:

```
SLComposeViewController * faceSheet=[self.socialIntegration showFacebook:@"text" andImage:nil andLink:@"link" andView:self];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //[self netConnectionTrue:cell Connected:answer];
            //[tempAlertView show];
            [self presentViewController:faceSheet animated:YES completion:NO];

        });
```

...you're not checking to see if `faceSheet` is nil. So if there's no Facebook account you call `presentViewController` with a nil object, which triggers the error you're seeing.

The reason you are seeing this on iOS 7 is your linked FB accounts probably got reset, but it was probably a source of crashes for your users on iOS 6 as well.

Comment: Thank you so very much! However in iOS 6 when the account was not linked it created a system alert window promoting the user to connect the account, why isn't that happening in iOS 7?

Comment: iOS 6 may have been more forgiving when passing `nil` to `presentViewController`...I'm not sure. Your alert view code looks OK to me.

Comment: It's really strange though because I can't think of a reason why apple  will ditch promoting the user to connect the account when it is not setup.

Comment: am getting settings page issue in IOS 7